# Obtain index of data frame row from iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have filtered a dataframe to obtain certain rows to match a condition. Now resulting `dataframe` (`test_acion_data`) has indices like this

```
Int64Index([ 115,  116,  186,  187,  199,  302,  303,  306,  314,  325 ...
            5745, 5746, 5747, 5748, 5749, 5750, 5751, 5752, 5753, 5754],dtype='int64', length=200)
```

I want to access each row of this test_action_data dataframe, and compare value of one column to corresponding column of next few rows of same dataframe. so I am using `test_action_data.iloc[j]`

```
for j in range(10):
     if(some condition):
         test_action_data.iloc[j].dropna(axis=0)
```

I am not getting any error, but rows are not getting dropped. Please help me here

Comment: add inplace=True in your dropna()

Comment: Could you post some of your data, particularly the data with null values?

Comment: adding inplace= True is not helping as well

Comment: @snapcrack : here is my data sample                              
 TimeStamp Type Action bootTime StartTime  StopTime tActionID totalIterations ISSUE_ID issueType
1496951774 Stop     action1 1496947681 1496951774 1496951774 2001 1  
1496951774 Start action2 1496947681 1496951774 0 2001 1  
1496951849 Start action3 1496947681 1496951849 0 2020 3  
1496951849 Start action4 1496947681 1496951849 0 2003 1  
1496951854 Stop   action5 1496947681 1496951849 1496951854 2003 1  
1496951968 Stop action6 1496951878 1496951967 1496951967 2001 1

Comment: I mean can you put it in your question in the proper column-row format?

Comment: This is my first time posting, sorry about the wrong format.  However, I figured out I can use    test_action_data.drop(test_action_data.index[j],inplace = True)    Thanks all for your quick responses